# Role Based Provisioning in OIM

Tags: oim

I have a project in Identity management for which I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  It's role-based provisioning, basically I need to know how to provision a specific application based on certain user attributes (e.g. job title, dept) and then to automatically raise a provisioning request for that application.  The application is a disconnected application and will be provisioned manually.

What we are trying to achieve is that once a user has been created in OIM and if he or she meets those criteria, the OIM will generate the request for the application so they can be provisioned for them.  Is there a way to implement this within OIM?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the scheme where a role in OIM has a membership rule to automatically grant a user the role if some of user's attribute match specific condition.

Then you can create an Access Policy to provision a disconnected resource and attach it to this created role. Usually disconnected resource provisioning will create a SOA workflow where there is a human task to complete the provisioning operation.

Comment: Hi Philip,Thanks for your response.  I understand the concept of what you are saying but am still very new to OIM and this is a project i was tasked with doing. could you share how exactly i can achieve this.  please pardon my ignorance. thanks

Comment: @Esogaco, what exactly do you have difficulties with? Try all of these components and let us know if you have any issues. It may also worth checking the [forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/fusion_middleware/identity_management) dedicated to OIM and related products

Comment: [Link to Access Policy documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40329_01/admin.1112/e27149/accesspolicies.htm#OMADM2250)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a Role with desired membership rule and an Access Policy attached to it. Role and membership rule can be created with OIM Role creation wizard. You can create a policy from admin console and associate your role and resource with it. Do provide default required parent form fields (at least IT Resource).

In case you want to add default entitlements edit the child form and add those.